# How should I generate mp3 files with unique id3 data for test data?

Tags: ios, testing, mp3, id3-tag

I am working with the iPod library on iOS to access audio for an audio player app and to properly test my system I need to generate a large number of test data. This means lots of mp3 files (and AAC/iTunes Plus) with unique meta data (id3) so that I can test loading up a large number of tracks to ensure it does not crash the app. My personal collection is less than 3000 tracks so it is not a fair test for users with 64GB iPhones that are loaded up with well over 10,000 tracks.

My initial plan would be to create a short 5 second audio track and set the meta data with artist, album, genre and other details. I would do this in another account on my Mac so that I would not interfere with my personal iTunes library. I would then sync this library to my iPod for testing.

Is there already a way to generate a test library with a large number of files with unique meta data? Is there an iOS compatible id3 tag library that I could use?

I've searched GitHub and did not find an Objective-C library for setting id3 tags.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can find loads of free mp3s at: http://mp3.com/

Comment: The point of generating small files is to get many more files on the iPod. If I just get typically sized files I will not be able to fit any more that I already do with my existing library.

Comment: Unless you are working with real data you won't getsome possible pitfalls. E.g. you are generating lots of random id3s. Afterwards you won't recognize that when there a lots of songs in a genre your library will crash. The tags could be longer then you exspect, etc...

Comment: I already have real data. This test will to be test a large number of items in the library so that I can work the code to scale to a large number of items. Just downloading many files also does not guarantee  better data.